# Merge two data frames in pandas giving "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically." using Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, jupyter-notebook

I want to merge two data frames using the merge function in pandas. When I want to do so on a common column, jupyter notebook gives me the following error "The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically." each data frame is about 50k rows. But when I try the same thing with only 50 rows from each data frame it works fine. I was wondering if anyone has a suggestion.

Comment: `50k x 50k` is approx 2.5 billion rows. does your system have enough ram for that?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a ram/memory issue with your machine. check the ram that you have and monitor it while you do the merge operation.